# QuickContactBadge showing contact's image

Tags: android, android-listview, quickcontactbadge

I'm trying to add a QuickContactBadge to a listview, it works fine and is clickable but currently shows no image, i'm sure there is a way to get it to display the contact's image but I'm not sure how. Can anyone help?

My code is:

```
    <QuickContactBadge android:id="@+id/contact"
    android:layout_width="54dp" android:layout_height="54dp"></QuickContactBadge>
```

and

```
    QuickContactBadge badgeSmall = (QuickContactBadge)messageView.findViewById(R.id.contact);  
    badgeSmall.assignContactFromEmail(message1.geteMail(), true);  
    badgeSmall.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_SMALL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/QuickContactsDemo.html). I think that what you need to make sure you do is that your cursor has the PHOTO_ID column included.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was an easier way.